# Power Query reference certain row

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am doing a query from a folder with many Excel files which all have the same structure. I want to reference a certain row which is always in the same place (row no. 5) in the same sheet in all of the excel files.
How can I do that? There is no reference point like a certain word that I could filter for, I just need row no. 5. The row sometimes is empty, partially filled or completely filled in. I need it in all 3 states.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

= Table.FromRecords(List.Transform(Folder.Files("YourFolderPath")[Content],each Excel.Workbook(_){0}[Data]{4}))

Comment: Thank you for your answer but somehow it doesn't work. In the meantime I found a workaround that seems to be right for now. (A custom sequence of filters)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will help.

I'm assuming you selected your query's source folder path and clicked Combine & Edit...
and picked a Sample file Parameter sheet and clicked OK to combine files...

[image]

So you'd see your appended worksheets result...something like this below. Note that my different workbooks in this example contain your different conditions for the 5th rows--empty, partially or completely filled.

[image]

All I think you really need to do from here is to add an index in the *"Transform Sample File from..."* query--in this example, it is the *"Transform Sample File from Test"* query since *Test* is what my folder was named and therefore what my query name was defaulted as.

Just select the *"Transform Sample File from..."* query, then *Add Column* > *Index Column*.

[image]

Then, when you click back on your main query...in this example...*Test*, you will see the index numbers, which you can use along with the *Source.Name* values for easy reference.

[image]

For instance, you could filter for *Index* value 4 (rows 5 of the worksheets) to see:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for!